# Water from peaked roof does not go into the gutter below. How do I fix this?

Tags: gutters, transition

I purchased a custom built home that has gutters, but there is a spot where the water from the peaked roof doesn't get into the gutter. It drips where the peaked roof hits the part with the gutter. Deadly in winter as huge icicles form and there is a 3" thick ice block on the deck under where it drips. During a rainstorm it is a waterfall. How do we guide the water from the peaked roof into the gutter? Is this a job for a roofer or a gutter installation company?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: image of icicles dripping from transition between roofs]

Comment: Hard to tell what the problem.  But I bet it can be fixed with a bit of flashing formed into a diverter.

Comment: On your picture of the front of the house - looking at the slider with the lights on either side it - could you circle the area where the ice cycles  are forming?  Is to above and to the left of the right most light?

Comment: It's not clear from your pictures where the water that would flow into the valley under your yellow circle (from the roof surrounding it) is supposed to go. Does the valley slope toward the front or unpictured-back of the house? If not, it's a major design flaw that is not easily remedied. If so, the downhill side needs some kind of gutter or downspout. If the pictured side is the uphill side of the valley, a metal plate (commonly used at the bottom end of step flashing above a gutter) as in @BaddDadd's answer would stop overflow from spilling over the roof edge before it flows downhill.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the last photo,it looks like water coming down the valley overshoots the gutter.  The solution would be aluminum sheet metal, in the corner where the water comes down.  In your first picture, there's a little ice in the inside corner (where the icicles are in the last photo).  Some sheet metal to stop the water from overflowing there, and directing it into the gutter would stop the icicles from forming.  When I had to add a small gutter section 25 years ago, the metal was there with the rest of the gutter and downspout stuff at Home Depot, so hopefully it's easy to find.